# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ResolvableType

Tags: java, spring, maven, wicket-7

I'm learning to develop with apache wicket, and I tried  to integrate Spring

this is the dependency into the `pom.xml` file

```
</dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
             <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
             <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring dependency -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

and this is the SpringIntegrationPage.java

```
public class SpringIntegrationPage extends WebPage {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ SpringBean(name="userModel")
    private UserModel userModel;
    public SpringIntegrationPage(){
        add(new Label("namelbl", new PropertyModel<String>(userModel, "name")));
        add(new Label("genderlbl", new PropertyModel<String>(userModel, "gender")));
        }
}
```

I get org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public com.beton.SpringIntegrationPage()
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ResolvableType

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public com.beton.SpringIntegrationPage()'. An exception has been thrown during construction!
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:194) ~[wicket-core-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at 
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462) [catalina.jar:7.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164) [catalina.jar:7.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) [catalina.jar:7.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562) [catalina.jar:7.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395) [catalina.jar:7.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.12]
    at 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175) ~[wicket-core-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ResolvableType
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this type (ResolvableType) was introduced in Spring 4.0, thus it wont we there in 3.0.5.RELEASE.
[check this page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.html)

So you might want to consider upgrading Spring version or use compatible version of wicket.

Comment: It's true, i have tried 4.0.6.RELEASE and its working, thanks

Comment: In my case upgrade to 4.0.6.RELEASE didn't helped. Upgrade to 4.1.9.RELEASE works fine.

Comment: Upgrading to `4.1.9.RELEASE` solved my problem. Thanks!